# Efficient way to add a colon before and after every word in strings inside a Series

Tags: python, strings, pandas

I was working with twitter data, and extracted every emoji from the data. But, when I passed that data through `CountVectorizer`, colons where substracted from the strings. So, the string emoji `:ok_hand: :thumbs_up:` turned into  `ok_hand thumbs_up`. I wanted to re-add those colons so then I could emojize them back. I managed to do that, but I'm quite sure my method is very inefficient. The emojis are the indexes of a coefficients DataFrame, like this:

```
    index              coef

ok_hand thumbs_up      0.4
    airplane           0.2
```

So what I did was this:

```
to_emojize=pd.Series(coef_mat_emoji.index)
to_emojize=to_emojize.apply(lambda x: x.split())
to_emojize=to_emojize.apply(lambda x:[':'+i+':' for i in x])
to_emojize=to_emojize.apply(lambda x: emoji.emojize(x, use_aliases=True))
coef_mat_emoji.index=to_emojize
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you could put all three steps into a single function and apply them in one iteration over the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `pandas.Series` and `pandas.Index` have vectorized string additions. You can just do:

```
to_emojize = pd.Series(":" + coef_mat_emoji.index + ":")
coef_mat_emoji.index = to_emojize.apply(emoji.emojize, use_aliases=True)
```

Note that `pandas.Series.apply` passes any additional keyword arguments along to the function, so there is no need for the `lambda` here at all.

This will create an intermediate series from the first addition, which might not be the most memory efficient way to do this. But it is the easiest and most readable, so unless you run out of memory with this, this is what I would use.

Alternatively you could put it all into one `apply` call (Python 3.6+ for `f-string`s):

```
coef_mat_emoji.index = pd.Series(coef_mat_emoji.index).apply(
                        lambda x: emoji.emojize(f":{x}:", use_aliases=True))
```

You would have to timeit with your actual data to see if this is any faster. It might be that the call to `emoji.emojize` will dominate anyway.